# Attach relation data directly to model

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship

**Article model**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Articles extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articles';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idArticle';

    protected $fillable = [
        'idArticle', 'Topic', 'Image', 'Content', 'Views',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'idCategory', 'idUser',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Categories::class, 'idCategory', 'idCategory');
    }
}
```

So now when i call `$article = Articles::find(1);`, it will returns data from articles table, when i add `$article->category;`, it adds data `$article->category->Name`. I would like to have that `Name` directly inside `$article` - something like `$article->category` (so `$article->category->Name` into `$article->category`) is it possible to define that just using model class or i need to map it inside controller?

Comment: you can use `eager loading', in controller write this `$article->load('category');` and then the category relation appends to your article collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign custom attributes to your Model classes.  But you can't use the same property name as your `category()` method, because it's already accessed by `$article->category`.

An example giving you a property called `category_name`

```php
class Articles extends Model
{
    // attributes to append to JSON responses
    protected $appends = ['category_name'];

    // ... your other properties and methods

    // your custom attribute
    public function getCategoryNameAttribute()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->category)) {
            return $this->category->Name;
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Use as:

```php
$article->category_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `appends`, as mentioned by @matticustard or just use the `->with()` method while retrieving your model:

```php
$article = Articles::find($id)->with('category');
```

Then, you can access the category name with:

```php
$categoryName = $article->category->name;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: He says he doesn't like to access name as `$article->category->name`. He would like to have the name attribute directly inside the `article` object.